# Разница между "соскучился" и "скучал"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какая разница между "соскучился" и "скучал"? Как правильно говорить?

Answer (score 2):

В сущности, разница как между процессом (скучал) и его результатом (соскучился). Из-за этого "соскучился" несёт б***о***льшую эмоциональную, экспрессивную нагрузку.

Соответственно, как Вам уже ответили, оба варианты правильны.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, разницы в значениях нет.Скучал в одиночестве - несов. вид. Соскучился в одиночестве - сов. вид; скучал по работе - соскучился по работе.

ВИКИ: Соскучиться 1.    впасть в состояние скуки, почувствовать скуку от чего-либо ◆синоним - заскучать
2.   почувствовать тоску от разлуки с кем-либо, чем-либо.Синоним- стосковаться

Скучать 1.  томиться от отсутствия интереса к происходящему, испытывать скуку .Синоним-тосковать, испытывать скуку
2.  болезненно переживать отсутствие кого-либо, чего-.Синоним - грустить
3.   устар. тяготиться чем-либо 
4.  устар. докучать, надоедать кому-либо